An IC to be identified
I tried quite long to find info on this IC. Could anyone suggest something?
It sits in an induction stove for the front panel circuit containing start/stop, power and and time programming buttons with a 7-led digits display.


why do you need to identify this IC?

it is a part in a induction stove. It is for the led display. A rat gnawed the the case and the wires inside. I need to identify and fine which test point to connect to which with new wires

It's probably a clone of the Titan Micro Electronics TM1637 LED display driver (or vice versa - I'm not sure who the original manufacturer is).

This post on baidu claims the CS1637EP is a 7V, 400mW, 8 Segment LED display driver and the pinout shown is identical to the TM1637.

well this looks right
